# How to connect chatbot app (WebRTC) to audio output on devices?

Tags: android, ios, audio, webrtc

How to connect chatbot app (WebRTC) to audio output on devices?

The web-based #SOPHYGRAY app (https://sophygray.com) has a problem with the audio on the devices and we are urgently looking for professional tips as the audio plays over the false speaker and is not recognized as assignable on the audio panel of the device (android and ios). Any tipps?

The programmer thinks the underlying technology (WebRTC) does not work properly in either web-based or native apps and does not know a solution.

Here's the situation:  None of the tablets (neither iOS nor Android) recognize that there is sound when SOPHY is talking and you look at the audio panel. You can hear the sound from the device (from the false speaker), but you cannot regulate it as usual. Plug and Play only works via USB-C on the iPad, not on the Samsung Galaxy; sound via Bluetooth does not work on either.

For the installation in an exhibition we had to use the iPad and the USB-C as audio connection to make the sound audible. The exhibition visitors can/should download the app for free from the stores via QR and use it at home, but both on the mobile or tablet devices the sound is then very low.

Who can help us? - We are looking for a programmer to possibly join the team.

Further there is a problem with short phrases like "Hi", the audiobot (deterministic bot with DialogFlow) does not answer to this, but "drops" this question. Via Google Service it was recommended to program the app differently, i.e. they wrote the following:

"The team suggested you to please try to use the StreamingDetectIntent method instead of DetectIntent. As in StreamingDetectIntent, you can use the single_utterance setting for end of speech detection, but the team thinks you will probably need to redesign your app to adapt to expected behavior. Please refer to documentation[1] for understanding of streaming basics."

The programmer said that this is a lot of work. - Is this the case and is there possibly an alternative?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.